# Jflex Regular expression for string with escaped characters

Tags: regex, flexbox, flex-lexer, lex, jflex

I am generating lexical analyzer with JFLEX. I need to find all strings which containing escaped characters using regular expressions. I'm struggling with this. What could it be?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to read [Jflex manual](https://jflex.de/manual.html). I think you can add any escape characters you want to the grammar like this code.

```
EscapeChar = \r | \n | \r\n | \t | \b                        //add more ...
Regex = ( [:jletterdigit:]* {EscapeChar}+ [:jletterdigit:]* )*
```

You can also use Unicode compliances either for all things that start with `\` but I'm not sure if it's a good way.

```
EscapeChar = \u005 [:jletter:]
Regex = ( [:jletterdigit:]* {EscapeChar}+ [:jletterdigit:]* )*
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I have a question. I wanted to get Strings (i..e starts with " and ends with " and then has escape chars in the middle. How do I do that? Do i add /* at the start and end?

Comment: Oh, I think you should use something like this `StringLiteral = \"[^(\\n|\\r)]~\"`. @izash

Comment: So that would get any string with both a starting " and ending ". It doesnt find if theres any escape chars in the middle. So I couldn't do Regex = ( {StringLiteral}+[:jletterdigit:]* {EscapeChar}+ [:jletterdigit:]* {StringLiteral}+)*. See the problem?